# What is an estimate of the value of the world's assets?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, statistics

Gross world product is on the order of 80E12 $ per year (PPP). Where can I find an estimate of the net value of the world's assets (companies, properties, infrastructure...)? Preferably with some more granular statistics.

Comment: It would take several aliens to make a market to buy the Earth. If only one shows up then the price will be low.

Answer (score 2):

One place that estimates the world's wealth (measured as net value of assets) is the [Credit Suisse Global Wealth Report](https://www.credit-suisse.com/about-us/en/reports-research/global-wealth-report.html).

According to the report their estimation of worlds net assets is 361 trillion of USD in 2019. Their site has also statistics for other years. They also offer some country level statistics in their reports (not sure if that's granular enough).

Comment: I dont under how this could be. This seems order of magnitudes off.

Comment: The article says 361 trillion, which makes much more sense.

Comment: @Brandon oh my bad I corrected it